# Python 3.5 CSV.reader returns no line

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, csv

I try to read an excel csv file.

```
 with open('test.csv') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel')
```

but csv.reader returns nothing. Inside the CSV file, the csv file is organized as follow:

04/30/2018,HFRX Absolute Return Index,HFRXAR,0.09%,1067.4

04/30/2018,HFRX ED: Distressed Restructuring Index,HFRXDS,0.44%,1051.13

04/30/2018,HFRX ED: Merger Arbitrage Index,HFRXMA,-0.80%,1816.23

04/30/2018,HFRX ED: Special Situations Index,HFRXSS,0.46%,1324.98

04/30/2018,HFRX EH: Equity Market Neutral Index,HFRXEMN,-0.07%,1011.05

04/30/2018,HFRX EH: Fundamental Growth Index,HFRXEHG,-1.89%,1766.22

04/30/2018,HFRX EH: Fundamental Value Index,HFRXEHV,0.11%,1233.52

04/30/2018,HFRX Emerging Markets Composite Index,HFRXEMC,-0.16%,1905.7

open function returns:

[image: open()]

and the csv.reader returns:

[image]

Any idea why I am not able to read this file?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `data = [r for r in reader]` after `csv.reader`, if there's a header call `header = next(reader)`

Comment: So simple, It works. I spent hours to find why I did not see the data inside csv.reader. Shame on me! Thank you very much.